# Why is ThunderBird downloading older messages even when only last 6 months are set for synchronization?

Tags: thunderbird, email, email-client

I have just created a new email account in Thuderbird for my msn email account.
And set ThunderBird to only synchronize last 6 months emails for this account yet its downloading emails as far back as 1 year and more.

Is there some other setting to limit ThunderBird from downloading the whole mailbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no !
It's a big issue that TBird developers just do not seem to care about.

It just does not make sense for Tbird to download every email since the beginning of time onto each computer on which you set it up.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Could you include some official sources, please?